# Zebra Print issue using asp.net with c#

Tags: asp.net

I am using the PrintDocument for printing directly to the network printer using asp.net with and C#. The application hosted in IIS with Windows authentication. I am not getting the error and also the PrintStatus is Printing. But we can not see the printed document in the printer and also there is no errors in the printer.

```
    System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument printdoc = new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument();          

    printdoc.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = new PaperSize("Custom", 4, 3);
    printdoc.OriginAtMargins = true;
    // Set the printer name
    PrinterSettings printer = new PrinterSettings();
    printer.PrinterName = SqlDatabaseUtility.GetZebraPrinterName();
    string fullName = CheckPrinterConfiguration(printer.PrinterName);
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(fullName))
    {
        printdoc.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = fullName;
        // Handle printing
        if (printdoc.PrinterSettings.IsValid)
        {
            printdoc.PrintPage += new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventHandler(printdoc_PrintPage);
            printdoc.PrinterSettings.Copies = 2;
            printdoc.Print();
        }
    }
```

Comment: If impersonation is off then it might be that asp.net account has no rights to print. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/306158/how-to-implement-impersonation-in-an-asp-net-application

Answer (score 0):

Just a theory, but the `PrintDocument` class is a descendant of `Component` and so implements `IDisposable`.

In the same way that you don't leave SqlConnection instances undisposed, you should call `Dispose()` on your printdoc instance so that any unmanaged resources held by the PrintDocument instance - such as a handle to the printer device, perhaps - get released.

Put a using clause around your printing block as below. It might help with your problem, but even if it does not it is proper practice.

```
using (System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument printdoc = new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument())          
{
    ...
}
```

The next line of enquiry would be to follow up on the "user permissions" suggestion in the comment. Assuming that your code works if you run it in a test console application, a quick test for this would be to change the user account of your web app's Application Pool to be your own account. If your web app starts printing, then you know that permissions are the problem.

Comment: Thanks Neil Moss, i have called the dispose in the finally block.